# Unauthorized client or scope in request

Tags: php, api

I can not get access to the Content API shopping (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content)

Next Error:

exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 "error": "unauthorized_client",
 "error_description": "Unauthorized client or scope in request."
}

That's part of the code, initialization

```
    $config_file = path to the file json

    $config = json_decode (file_get_contents ($config_file));

    $client = new Google_Client ();

    $client->setScopes ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content');

    $client->setAuthConfig ($config_file);

    $this->service = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent ($client);
```

What was done:

1 Create an account Merchant Center, confirmed the right of the site

2 Create a project in console.developers.google.com

3 Turn on the Content API for Shopping

4 Created Credentials - Service account key - json

5 Permissions - Service account - Enable Google Apps Domain-wide Delegation

6 Tried to add a rule to admin.google (as written https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), but no results.

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Have the same problem, only difference is I'm trying to use the Calendar API.